# CSS, let only 1 child extend outside parent. Float image must stay inside

Tags: css

I have a parent container. It has some text, a float:right image and an options box. Normally the options box is not visible. However, when it is, it must appear on top of the text below it (so position:absolute).

The issue is that the options box needs to extend outside the parent, while the other elements must stay inside the parent. Or, the options box should expand the parent, but still be on top of the text.

Position:fixed won't work because it must be possible to scroll. 
I have created a fiddle to illustrate the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/VU5Ub/1/

The image is outside the parent.

```
<div id = "page">
    <div id = "parent">
        <div id = "top_text">Pick 1:</div>
        <div id = "image"> </div>
        <div id = "x">&nbsp;
             <div id = "options"></div>
        </div>
        <div>i get hidden by the options, as desired</div>
    </div>
</div>

#page{height:230px;}
#parent{width:200px;
    background:red;
    overflow:visible;
}
#top_text{float:left;}
#options{height:200px;
    background:yellow;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2

}
#x{position:relative;}
#image{height:90px;
       width:40px;
        float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
    background:pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by adding a last line after everything else:

```
#lastline{clear:both;height:0px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VU5Ub/3/

Answer (score 0):

Stop using

> float: left;
>
> float: right;

use

> display: inline-block;

instead. In this way your image will expand the parent element.

Comment: But then the text doesn't flow around the image.

Answer (score 0):

my solution is: use a height for your image,say 100px and make min-height of your parent 100px here is my css

```
#image{
 height:100px;
 width:40px;
 float:right;
 margin-right:10px;
 background:pink;
}
#parent{
 width:200px;
 background:red;
 overflow:visible;
 min-height:100px;
}
```

you may check it here:  **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Vc3AF/)**

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing. Does mean that I have to know the combined minimum height of the image and whatever text is above and below it, but that seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Just came up with another solution.